# Highlight only a portion of a search term in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a way to have vim's search highlighting work on only a part of my search term.

I'm viewing a huge log file of data dumps. It looks something like this:
field1: 12345
field2: 12345
field3: 12345
field4: 12345
field5: 12345
...
field1: 11111
field2: 22222
field3: 33333
...
and so on.

I'd like to be able to have all of the fieldX values highlighted for a moment, then quickly switch to highlighting the values for fieldY. Is it possible to search for something like 'field3: \d\d\d\d\d' and have only the number part highlighted?

So in searching for 'my highlight search term' I'd like only 'highlight' to get highlighted.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you can try searching like this:

```
/field3: \zs\d\d\d\d\d
```

That will highlight any numbers (and only the numbers) that come after `field3:`

For quick switching, you could try: `/`, `up-arrow`, change `field3` to `field2`.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: \ze is the other bit that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

well highlight fieldY i'm not sure (a lil bit of a vim noob) but you should be able to just goto the next work by typing  `w`

to get to the next fieldX, type  `n`

this won't highlight fieldy but it will put your cursor at the beginning of that number

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're searching, but running:

```
:%!column -t
```

will make your columns more visible